# Failed to resolve component (client) in Nuxt3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to import Quill Editor into a Nuxt3 project and want to use it in a componenent.

This is what I am trying to do:

`QuillEditorWrapper.client.vue`

```
<script>
import '../node_modules/@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css';
export default {
  name: 'NotQuillEditor',
  setup() {
    if (process.client) {
      const { QuillEditor } = import('@vueup/vue-quill');
      return { QuillEditor };
    }
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <h1>Quill Editor</h1>
  <QuillEditor theme="snow" toolbar="full" /> <!-- same for <quill-editor> -->
</template>
```

This mounts the component but does not launch quill editor. The following vue warning is displayed:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: QuillEditor
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

A full reproduction is available here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-qsdpjt-me572c?file=components/QuillEditorWrapper.client.vue

Comment: my guess is that you are not propoerly importing the component . `const { QuillEditor } = import('@vueup/vue-quill');` feels wrong to me. 
Try importing it at top: `import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'`

Comment: No that does not change anything if I `import QuillEditor from '@vueup/vue-quill';
` before `export default`

Comment: did you add `components: { QuillEditor }` at same level than name and setup